# What alternatives to glass are there for framing glossy prints?

Tags: prints, presentation, frames

I ordered photos through an online service. Print is pretty good; the photos are glossy, so I'm wondering if there is any alternative to glass. I think putting glossy photos under glass would make them shine even more. However glass also protects them from dust, although that might not be that important considering most of the paintings don't have glass on them. However I've seen some nice prints done, where the paper goes around the edges of the frame so that the photo is seen on the sides as well. I don't know if that's possible with already printed photos or should I order this style straight from print shop.

Photos are 10x8 inch, which is roughly A4 size.

What options do I have?

Answer (score 2):

What you are referring to is a gallery wrap. This must be ordered from a print shop directly as it involves a special process. This is most *commonly* offered on canvas but some places do it on other materials. [WHCC](http://www.whcc.com/products/wall-displays/gallery-wraps), for example, offers it on metallic and photographic paper.

You are right that glass is not needed for framing. You can use a frame without glass which is easiest with a *matte* that fits into a frame. This gives a look where the frame is over-sized with respect to the print. You can also *mount* instead and use foam-core, vinyl or other materials which are both rigid and relatively light. It is easiest to order the finished product but you can do your own mounting by getting the right materials from an art-supply store.

Answer (score 1):

A glossy print under glass looks fine - at least as far as I can tell from a glossy print under glass in front of my nose.
However you can have glass with an anti-reflective coating to reduce gloss, that is not so much the print but the glass itself.

As to having photos span over edges - I guess you mean a canvas print? That's where the image extends beyond the immediate frame.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are talking about "canvas", this is how I have most of my pictures printed, some places even mount frames (with no glass) on your canvas print, which can look really nice, to my knowledge, canvas prints are always matte.

Comment: Since, as you say, canvas prints are almost by definition matte, that probably _isn't_ what the question is talking about.